# Problem starting tkinter files using import

Tags: python, file, tkinter, import

I'm trying to make my code smaller by using import instead of os.startfile() to open my other .pyw code.
I'm having some problems with starting one of the files.

Here is my code:

```
import os, subprocess, sys
from tkinter import messagebox, Tk, Label, Entry, Button

import home


def start():
     home.start()


root = Tk()


Button(root, text="Go", command=start).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

(Where Home is the tkinter file I'm trying to start)

And this is the error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pdann.DESKTOP-8GHUG6R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\PYOS\login.pyw", line 21, in Ok
    home.start()
  File "F:\PYOS\home.pyw", line 81, in start
    main_btn = Button(root, image= main_icon, command= more_apps, borderwidth= 7)
  File "C:\Users\Pdann.DESKTOP-8GHUG6R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2679, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Pdann.DESKTOP-8GHUG6R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

In the file I'm opening I have the start() function around the Tkinter code.
I've done this with plenty of other Tkinter gui (pyw) files, but this is the one that doesn't work.

To make things clear, I am trying to start another file of mine with import home, then home.start() which is the function to start the whole thing.

Comment: It looks like you've created more than once instance of `Tk`.

Comment: how would I fix it in this case?

Comment: Use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` inside `home.pyw`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the import. Try:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and than

```
tk.TK()
```

Comment: Why would this fix the problem? I'm just trying to start another file.

Comment: I had a similar problem (_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist), and I fixed it changing the import.

Comment: I tried this on both the file that is importing and the imported file, but I came up with the same error.

Comment: So the problem is something that conflicts with something else. You need to dig deeper into the code and figure out what's conflicting with Tkinter.